# converting vb.net to c#- optimise parameter passing

Tags: c#, vb.net, parameters, byref, byval

I want to move a vb.net app to c#. The vb.net app has thousands of byref parameters that should be byval. Does anybody know a way to automate checking whether each parameter passing approach can be safely changed?

Comment: You could search for `refVariable =`. Then you should not make it `ByVal`. But you have to do it manually(use VS function _find all references_).

Comment: Sounds like an answer, tim!

Comment: yes, you might use the `find and replace` feature of Visual Studio `:)`

Answer (score -2):

maybe the following tool http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ can help you.

Comment: -1 how does it help to determine whether [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) is required or not?

Comment: Thanks for getting back guys...the developerfusion tool is great but I'm not allowed to send code outside the company. I think I'll have to do what I can with regex and then just start in on debugging. Tim's idea of looking for refVar= is probably worth a crack.]